# Listview embedded in a ExpandableListActivity is only partially displayed on the screen

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I use a `ListView` as the child row in a `ExpandableListActivity` and have defined a custom `CursorTreeAdapter` for it. The values and the views are being populated by my code just as expected, but each expandable list row (`ListView` with variable number of items in it) is only partially shown (only the first 2 items are being displayed).

1. While debugging through the code, I confirmed that all the child rows (`ListView`) are being populated properly (that is with 10-15 rows in it)
2. Just to confirm further, I changed `android:stackFromBottom = "true"` for the `ListView`, this time only the last 2 items were displayed for each expandable item row.

`

```
public class WorkExpandableListAdapter extends CursorTreeAdapter {

public WorkExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context) { super(cursor, context, true); }

 protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) { ... return childCursor; }

 @Override
 protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
   boolean isLastChild) {

  if (!noColumnsToDisplay) {
   int numColumns = workProjection.length + 1; // to skip the _id
   ArrayList<JXTField> jxtFields = new ArrayList<JXTField>();
   for (int i = 1; i < numColumns; i++) {
    jxtFields.add(new JXTField(workProjection[i - 1],
      cursor.getString(cursor
        .getColumnIndex(workProjection[i - 1]))));
   }

//OrderAdapter is simply a customized Array adapter which converts name value pairs into //customized 2 line items

   ArrayAdapter<JXTField> adapter = new OrderAdapter(WorkList.this,
     R.layout.work_view_row, jxtFields);
   ((ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_child_list))
     .setAdapter(adapter);
  }
 }

 @Override
public View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
  return getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandable_child_list,null); }

 @Override
protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) { ... }

 @Override
 protected View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
  return ((TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, null));
 }
}
```

`

**expandable_child_list.xml**

`

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/expandable_child_listt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"      
    android:layout_weight="2.0"     
    />
```

`

**work_view_row.xml**   `

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/work_view_row_top_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/work_view_row_bottom_text"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

This looked like an easy one to solve when I first encountered it, but after wasting too much time on it I resort to the gurus. Maybe I am missing something very obvious, but please point out. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using a subclassed `ListView` which overrides `onMeasure()`.

The following 2 posts were very helpful in pointing me in the right direction.
1. [How do I create a ListView that's not in a ScrollView, or has the ScrollView disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419246/how-do-i-create-a-listview-thats-not-in-a-scrollview-or-has-the-scrollview-disa)
2. [Calculate the size of a list view or how to tell it to fully expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312683/calculate-the-size-of-a-list-view-or-how-to-tell-it-to-fully-expand)

However, I still feel this was a bloated work around, and have no idea why the view returned by `newChildView()` does not allow `ListView` to expand fully even when `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` is set for the `ListView` and its container (`LinearLayout`).

It would be great, if someone can point out the reason.
Thank you.